# Postgres Database - One object links to one or mare objects from Same table

Tags: database, postgresql

This is a senario:

I have got a object let's say a cat. For example when I insert the cat 4 details to database, I can add cats to cat 4, lets say cat 1, 2 and 3.In web page, when I click on cat 4 link, I need to open new page with details of cat 4 plus cat 1, 2 and 3.

I am not wondering about the frontend implementation, I only want to know how can this be designed in database. I do not think this is related to inheritance since we are dealing with same type of object which is a cat.

I can make it simple by creating a array field in cat table that contains children's ids, but I am not sure if this is the best solution. Or It could be better way to implement this in Postgres database.

Comment: Please add more information:  How many levels of children can you add?  Can you assume that each child has only one parent?  These details determine how this relationship is best modeled in the database.

Comment: Good question @MikeOrganek. It is only one level. The reason for this when the user click on cat link in the page, it will open new page which shows the selected cat and its linked cats (children).

Comment: I have edited my Post to clarify this more.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
-- Cat Table
CREATE TABLE Cat (
cat_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255),
-- Other cat details...
);

-- CatHierarchy Table
CREATE TABLE CatHierarchy (
parent_cat_id INT REFERENCES Cat(cat_id),
child_cat_id INT REFERENCES Cat(cat_id),
PRIMARY KEY (parent_cat_id, child_cat_id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you @mahmoud-hossam, it seems your answer using inheritance. But my requirement does not look need inheritance solution. It is true that my title of the post says "Parent/Children relationship" but what I need it just to link objects with one object, this can be apply to any solution not just cat example. The cat example is just example to explain what I need.

Comment: I have edited my Post to clarify this more.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrays for this, they can't maintain data integrity.

Something like this could work:

```
CREATE TABLE animals(
    id_animal INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    , id_animal_type INT -- foreign key to animal types, like cat, dog, etc
    , id_mom INT REFERENCES animals(id_animal)
    , id_dad INT REFERENCES animals(id_animal)
    , gender CHAR(1) CHECK ( gender IN('m','f') )
    , name TEXT
    -- etc
);
```

Comment: Thank you @mahmoud-hossam, it seems your answer using inheritance. But my requirement does not look need inheritance solution. It is true that my title of the post says "Parent/Children relationship" but what I need it just to link objects with one object, this can be apply to any solution not just cat example. The cat example is just example to explain what I need.

Comment: I have edited my Post to clarify this more.